# how to select elements which their names are array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

How I can get the values of these elements and post them as array by ajax:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[m]"/> Members
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[i]"/> IATA agencies
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[n]"/> non-IATA agencies
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[c]"/> Commitees
```

Comment: your title is not understandable ? By values of these elements mean ?

Comment: You are not given value to your checkbox so you cannot post that values

Comment: @Sadikhasan its just a quick example

Comment: @user2101939 Provide code with proper data so user can understand easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

First change your input name to simply name="Broadcast[]"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[]" value="Members"/> Members
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[]" value="IATA agencies"/> IATA agencies
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[]" value="non-IATA agencies"/> non-IATA agencies
<input type="checkbox" name="Broadcast[]" value="Commitees"/> Commitees
```

and then in jquery to send the data in array via ajax, create a  variable to mapping all the values to an array.

**jquery:**

```
var BroadCast = $("input[name='BroadCast\\[\\]']").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

and put the variable BroadCast into the ajax data.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:'your action url',
    data: {BroadCast: BroadCast},
    success:function(data){
    //do what you want here
    }
```

});

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The map function search for elements with the same name like the each function of jquery. on using return $(this).val() i receive the value of the finding element at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = $("input[type=checkbox][name^=Broadcast]"), values = [];
items.each(function(){
    values.push([$(this).attr("name"),$(this).is(":checked")]);
});
console.log(values);
```

sorry was wrong before, here is a fiddle for you
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq3k2wLa/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `serialize` method to do this.first in your html add value to checkboxes and remove whatever inside [] and make it `name='Broadcast[]'` for each checkbox.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:'your url',
    data:$("form").serialize(),
    success:function(data){
    //do stuff here
    }

});
```